# Oracle audit: Only 'SESSION REC' in ACTION_NAME column

Tags: oracle, oracle-9i, audit

I was asked to generate a report of operations performed on certain Oracle 9i tables in a given period of time.

When I query the `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL` table I only get `SESSION REC` in the `ACTION_NAME` column.

I was expecting `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` etc.

- What am I doing wrong?
- What does `SESSION REC` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means you set `AUDIT .. BY SESSION` instead of `AUDIT .. BY ACCESS`. When you use `BY SESSION`, the `ACTION_NAME` contains `SESSION REC`, and the actual actions performed by that session are stored in the `SES_ACTIONS` column as characters. For example the value `---------S------` means there was a select on the object, as each character represents the following actions in order:

`ALTER, AUDIT, COMMENT, DELETE, GRANT, INDEX, INSERT, LOCK, RENAME, SELECT, UPDATE, REFERENCES, and EXECUTE`

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch2205.htm#1307791